# Appium version issue

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, android, eclipse

I am confused to see what Appium version is installed on my machine. If I look into Appium UI it shows Appium v1.22.3 but When I check from cmd it shows 2.0.0-beta.71. how do I know which one is correct?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have installed Appium using a package manager, and also you have download the Appium GUI.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/38046)

Comment: @IAmMilinPatel Hi, If this is not the answer , what might be a possible answer ?

Comment: The OP wants to know the correct way to check the version of Appium installed in their computer. Your answer doesn't help in this in any way.

Comment: @IAmMilinPatel Ooh Thanks for that. Let me adjust the answer.